# Join XML columns from SQL Server 2016+

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a `TABLE_A` with an XML column `mycategoryXML` which contains this XML:

```
<mainxml>
     <category id="1" ftype="1"/>
     <category id="2" ftype="1"/>
     <category id="3" ftype="1"/>
</mainxml>
```

I also have another `TABLE_B` with a XML column called `mymappedids`

```
<mapids>
    <ids>
        <myid id="1" name="Category Name1"/>
        <myid id="2" name="Category Name2"/>
        <myid id="3" name="Category Name3"/>
        <myid id="4" name="Category Name4"/>
        <myid id="5" name="Category Name5"/>
        <myid id="6" name="Category Name6"/>
        <myid id="7" name="Category Name7"/>
        <myid id="8" name="Category Name8"/>
        <myid id="9" name="Category Name9"/>
    </ids>
</mapids>
```

Is it possible to select all `Category` nodes from `TABLE_A` and also the correct  names for each category from `table_B`, so I ultimately get the follow result:

```
      id | categoryid | categoryname
      ---+------------+-------------
      1  |    1       | categoryname1
      2  |    2       | categoryname2
      3  |    3       | categoryname3
```

with one query from SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, you can use XQUERY on both, and then either implicitly join in the `WHERE`. Or use subqieries and `JOIN` them if you need an Outer Join of some kind. What were your attempts, and why didn't they work?

Comment: so can you answwer it with an example and i will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several approaches but you did not tell us enough about your background.

Especially unclear: How is the connection between these two tables a and b?

You might try something along this:

A *mockup scenario* to simulate your issue (please provide this yourself in your next question):

```
DECLARE @tblA TABLE(aId INT,Xml1 XML);
DECLARE @tblB TABLE(bId INT,Xml2 XML);

INSERT INTO @tblA(aId,Xml1) VALUES
(100
,N'<mainxml>
     <category id="1" ftype="1"/>
     <category id="2" ftype="1"/>
     <category id="3" ftype="1"/>
</mainxml>');
INSERT INTO @tblB(bId,Xml2) VALUES
(200
,N'<mapids>
    <ids>
        <myid id="1" name="Category Name1"/>
        <myid id="2" name="Category Name2"/>
        <myid id="3" name="Category Name3"/>
        <myid id="4" name="Category Name4"/>
        <myid id="5" name="Category Name5"/>
        <myid id="6" name="Category Name6"/>
        <myid id="7" name="Category Name7"/>
        <myid id="8" name="Category Name8"/>
        <myid id="9" name="Category Name9"/>
    </ids>
</mapids>');
```

--The query

```
SELECT a.aId
      ,aXmlValues.* 
      ,(SELECT Xml2.value('(/mapids
                            /ids
                            /myid[@id=sql:column("aXmlValues.CategoryId")]
                            /@name)[1]','nvarchar(max)') 
        FROM @tblB b
        WHERE bID=200 /*however you find this...*/) AS CategoryName
FROM @tblA a
CROSS APPLY a.Xml1.nodes('/mainxml/category') aXml(c)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT aXml.c.value('@id','int') AS CategoryId
                  ,aXml.c.value('@ftype','int') AS CategoryType) aXmlValues;
```

The idea in short:

- We use `APPLY ... .nodes()` to get the categories of table "a" in separate rows (a derived set).
- now we can use `APPLY` again. This is a trick to get the XML's value into the result set as a *normal column*.
- This column can be placed into XQuery against table "b" using `sql:column()`.

Comment: Thank you so much i was trying sql:column("catxml.value('(//category/id[@id=1])[1]','nvarchar(max)'") and i was getting thousand results when i try 3 cross apply .You save me 2 days searching THANK YOU so much again!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you likely want something like this:

```
DECLARE @XML1 xml = '<mainxml>
     <category id="1" ftype="1"/>
     <category id="2" ftype="1"/>
     <category id="3" ftype="1"/>
</mainxml>';

DECLARE @XML2 xml = '<mapids>
    <ids>
        <myid id="1" name="Category Name1"/>
        <myid id="2" name="Category Name2"/>
        <myid id="3" name="Category Name3"/>
        <myid id="4" name="Category Name4"/>
        <myid id="5" name="Category Name5"/>
        <myid id="6" name="Category Name6"/>
        <myid id="7" name="Category Name7"/>
        <myid id="8" name="Category Name8"/>
        <myid id="9" name="Category Name9"/>
    </ids>
</mapids>';

SELECT X1.c.value('@id','int') AS id,
       X2.mi.value('@id','int') AS categoryid,  --Seem silly to have this value twice
       X2.mi.value('@name','varchar(30)') AS categoryname
FROM (VALUES(@XML1)) V1(X)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(@XML2)) V2(X)
     CROSS APPLY V1.X.nodes('/mainxml/category')X1(c)
     CROSS APPLY V2.X.nodes('/mapids/ids/myid')X2(mi)
WHERE X1.c.value('@id','int') = X2.mi.value('@id','int');
```